# How to add a Custom Meta Box for more than one Post Type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I am using the following code in `functions.php` for adding a custom meta box.

The custom post type is `themes`. I want to add more post types, how can I?

```
add_meta_box( 
    'my-meta-box-id', 
    'Demo & Download', 
    'cd_meta_box_cb', 
    'themes', 
    'normal', 
    'high' 
);
```

Comment: Do you want to add more Custom Post Types or *add the same metabox* to other post types?

Comment: I want to add same meta box to other post types too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever in doubt about a WordPress function, consult the Codex.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

There, you'll see that you need to add one meta box to each post type.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box' );

function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'myplugin_sectionid',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
        'post' 
    );
    add_meta_box(
        'myplugin_sectionid',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ), 
        'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
        'page'
    );
}
```